# Unable to Add widget for New products in Hompage Using Magento 2 release alpha96

Tags: magento2, widgets

Anybody can guide me on how to display products in homepage in Magento 2? 
In Magento 2 Backend, Content->Pages->Home Page->Content,
I am trying to insert Widget for New products on homepage but I am not successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason the widget selector does not work in alpha96. I will post an issue soon on github.
But you can make it work manually. Add this to the homepage content from CMS->Pages:

```
<p>{{widget type="Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\Widget\\NewWidget" template="product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}</p>
```

I tried with single backslashes `type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget"` but it does not work.

Comment: Thank you Marius for the help. The snippet you gave works fine. :D